# 手書き文字の前処理のやり方

Tags: python

現在、手書き文字の前処理のやり方を学んでいる学生です。どうしても原因が分からないエラーが出たので、プロフェッショナルの皆様の力をお借りしたいと思い、質問いたします。

画像の明瞭化、グレースケール化、縮小化、明暗反転、その後の、Imageオブジェクトの特徴ベクトルへの変換までできたのですが、それ以降の「特徴ベクトルをpredict()メソッドに渡す」という部分ができません。

「This LogisticRegression instance is not fitted yet」というエラーが出てしまいます。

コードは以下です。

```
pip install pillow

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('mydigit.jpg')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(im)

from PIL import ImageEnhance

im_enhanced = ImageEnhance.Brightness(im).enhance(2.0)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(im_enhanced)

im_gray = im_enhanced.convert(mode='L')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(im_gray, cmap='gray')

im_8x8 = im_gray.resize((8, 8))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(im_8x8, cmap='gray')

from PIL import ImageOps

im_inverted = ImageOps.invert(im_8x8)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(im_inverted, cmap='gray')

import numpy

X_im2d = numpy.asarray(im_inverted)
X_im2d

X_im1d = X_im2d.reshape(-1)
X_im1d

X_multiplied = X_im1d * (16 / 255)
X_multiplied

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, solver='liblinear', multi_class='auto')

clf.predict(X_multiplied)[0]
```

以下エラー文

```
NotFittedError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-0e0508a3ae41> in <module>
----> 1 clf.predict(X_multiplied)[0]

~\Test\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in predict(self, X)
    287             Predicted class label per sample.
    288         """
--> 289         scores = self.decision_function(X)
    290         if len(scores.shape) == 1:
    291             indices = (scores > 0).astype(np.int)

~\Test\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in decision_function(self, X)
    261         if not hasattr(self, 'coef_') or self.coef_ is None:
    262             raise NotFittedError("This %(name)s instance is not fitted "
--> 263                                  "yet" % {'name': type(self).__name__})
    264 
    265         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')

NotFittedError: This LogisticRegression instance is not fitted yet
```

Comment: エラーメッセージから `clf` インスタンスに問題がある事が分かるのですが、この `clf` はどの様に定義されているのでしょうか？

Comment: from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, solver='liblinear', multi_class='auto')
clf   です

Comment: sklearn のソースコードや LogisticRegression のサンプルコードを読むと、 `predict` メソッドを実行する前に `fit` メソッドで学習済みデータを読み込む必要がある様に見えます。

Comment: 参考: [scikit-learn/plot_iris_logistic.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/examples/linear_model/plot_iris_logistic.py)

Comment: 申し訳ありません、リンク先を読んでも解決できず、、、metropolisさんだったら、どのようにコードを書きますか？

Comment: 画像ファイル名(`mydigit.jpg`)から、数字の画像かと推測します。そうでしたら、sklearn.dataset には `load_digits` というメソッドがあり、手書き数字(0~9)の画像を利用できます(MNISTのデータでも良いかと思います)。これを `fit` メソッドに与えると良いかと思います。具体的なコードの書き方については [Logistic Regression using Python (scikit-learn)](https://towardsdatascience.com/logistic-regression-using-python-sklearn-numpy-mnist-handwriting-recognition-matplotlib-a6b31e2b166a) が参考になるかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

学習していないのに、予測できないですよってことです。

scikit-learnであれば、どのアルゴリズムを使う場合でも、基本的に`fit()`で学習して、`predict()`で予測します。もちろん学習済みのモデルがあれば、それをロードしてもいいですが。

そもそも、予測は「手書き文字の前処理」ではないですね。